# Return specific fields for elasticsearch in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch-2.0

This seems like a really easy issue, but everything I've tried from other solutions and websites is not working. I have three fields I do not want indexed or queried--`:p_s`, `:gender`, and `:part_of_speech`--but elasticsearch is still returning values from those fields even though I don't specify that they should be indexed or queried. About halfway down, [this article](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/mapping-intro.html) says to say `no` to indexing, but they don't indicate where this would occur.

Term Controller:

```
  def search
    @terms = Term.search(params[:query]).page(params[:page])
  end
```

Model:

```
require 'elasticsearch/model'

class Term < ActiveRecord::Base

include Elasticsearch::Model
include Elasticsearch::Model::Callbacks

  settings index: { number_of_shards: 1, number_of_replicas: 0 },
    do

    mappings dynamic: 'false' do
      indexes :id, index: :not_analyzed
      indexes :name, analyzer: :spanish_analyzer
      indexes :definition, analyzer: :combined_analyzer
      indexes :etymology1, analyzer: :combined_analyzer
      indexes :etymology2, analyzer: :combined_analyzer
      indexes :uses, analyzer: :combined_analyzer
      indexes :notes1, analyzer: :combined_analyzer
      indexes :notes2, analyzer: :combined_analyzer
    end
  end

  def self.search(query)
    __elasticsearch__.search(
      {
        query: {
          multi_match: {
            query: query,
            fields: ['name^7', 'definition^6', 'etymology1^5', 'etymology2^4', 'uses^3', 'notes1^2', 'notes2^1'],
            operator: 'and'
          }
        }
      }
    )
  end
end

# Delete the previous term index in Elasticsearch
Term.__elasticsearch__.client.indices.delete index: Term.index_name rescue nil

# Create the new index with the new mapping
Term.__elasticsearch__.client.indices.create \
  index: Term.index_name,
  body: { settings: Term.settings.to_hash, mappings: Term.mappings.to_hash }

# Index all term records from the DB to Elasticsearch
Term.import(force: true)
```

Answer (score 1):

To mark a field as non-indexed use this:

```
mappings dynamic: 'false' do
    ...
    indexes :p_s, index: :no
    indexes :gender, index: :no
    indexes :part_of_speech, index: :no
    ...
end
```

By default elasticsearch returns all document fields under `"_source"` key. To only get specific fields you can either specify `fields` array on the ***top query*** level like this

```
def self.search(query)
    __elasticsearch__.search(
      {
        query: {
          multi_match: {
            query: query,
            fields: ['name^7', 'definition^6', 'etymology1^5', 'etymology2^4', 'uses^3', 'notes1^2', 'notes2^1'],
            operator: 'and'
          }
        },
        fields: ['name', 'definition', 'etymology1', 'etymology2', 'uses', 'notes1', 'notes2']
      }
    )
  end
```

or filter `"_source"`

```
def self.search(query)
    __elasticsearch__.search(
      {
        query: {
          multi_match: {
            query: query,
            fields: ['name^7', 'definition^6', 'etymology1^5', 'etymology2^4', 'uses^3', 'notes1^2', 'notes2^1'],
            operator: 'and'
          }
        },
        '_source': ['name', 'definition', 'etymology1', 'etymology2', 'uses', 'notes1', 'notes2']
      }
    )
end
```

[See Elasticsearch source filtering docs for more.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-source-filtering.html)

When using `multi_match` clause, the inner `fields` element specifies the fields to run the search on and, optionally, the boost like in your example. The outer `fields` or '_source' clause in turn determines which fields to return and this is the one you're after.

To have a better visibility into what's going on while debugging elasticsearch queries, use a tool like [Sense](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sense-beta/lhjgkmllcaadmopgmanpapmpjgmfcfig?hl=en). When you get the result you want it may be much easier to transfer the query to ruby code than vice versa.

Comment: Okay, I tried specifying fields in the top level query, but I receive this error `undefined method `slug' for #<Elasticsearch::Model::Response::Result` and it points to this is my search view template `<a href="/term/<%=term.slug %>"><%= term.name %></a>` I deleted the link and performed the query again but received the same error for `term.name`

Comment: I tried the `_source` method as well, but I think I'm putting it in the wrong location/not typing it correctly.  I've read tons of documentation and try hard to understand, but as a newbie, I find a lot of this goes over my head. For instance, how am I supposed to apply this line `"term" : { "user" : "kimchy" }` to my code? I don't really get what I'm supposed to replace it with.

Comment: Please see the updated example on `"_source"` usage.

Comment: I tried both `'_source'` and `_source` for good measure, but now it's returning the same error that I'm having with the other person helping me. I even added `Term.__elasticsearch__.refresh_index!(force: true)` at the end of my model per his suggestion, but that didn't help.

Comment: What was this error? Note that template errors related to `<a href="/term/<%=term.slug %>"><%= term.name %></a>` may have nothing to do with the query working correctly. This is because depending on your query configuration the resulting dataset structure may be different. This is why it is important to check the raw outcome of the query before trying to use it down the line.

Comment: Elasticsearch output was giving me this error: `/search Params: {query=prefix, index=search}
[search] IndexNotFoundException[no such index]`. One thing I decided to do was change this method `self.search(query)` to `self.terms(query)` which allows me to search again but still returns all fields. Although, it's now providing this error message: `/terms Params: {index=terms}
[terms] IndexAlreadyExistsException[already exists]` which makes sense, but I'm not sure how to proceed. I also updated my original post with the search method I have defined in my TermsController in case that helps.

Comment: Remove `Term.__elasticsearch__.refresh_index!(force: true)` and `Term.import(force: true)`. Don't mix index definition and interaction code which is in your model with index maintenance code which is better placed in a separate task. Revert the code to its original state, rebuild the index from console and copy the `search` method from one of my examples. Run the `Term.search` from console and observe the result.

Answer (score 0):

I think using the included `elasticsearch` methods makes a lot of sense. However, in my own case, in my model I did something like this, modified for your own case:

```
def as_indexed_json
  as_json(only: [:id, :name, :definition, :etymology1, :etymology2, :uses, :notes1, :notes2])
end
```

This should work because by default Elasticsearch would call the `as_indexed_json` method in your model to get the data it needs to index.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I had a new issue come up that I needed to solve first...Your solution is one of the methods I tried that didn't work for me. To be clear, this code should take the place of my `def self.search(query)` method, no? It also should go after my mappings, right?

Comment: With this method in place you wouldn't need to do the mappings anymore, because those fields would not be indexed anymore and therefore cannot be queried at all. Your search can still remain the way it is and I guess all other configurations can be done in your settings.

Comment: hmm, well I tried just as you said, but it's still returning those extra fields that I don't want included

Comment: Did you reindex the table?

Comment: I placed `Term.__elasticsearch__.refresh_index!(force: true)` after `Term.import(force: true)` at the bottom of my model, but that didn't change anything. I even closed down elasticsearch and fired it back up as well as dopped the db and migrated and seeded it again to no avail